# Putting Variables Between | | in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

In Ruby code, I noticed some variables or other objects placed in between `| |`. I have no idea why. Is it usually used in hashmaps?

Comment: Hi Domani! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks context and code examples. As a person that hasn't seen the specific code you're talking about, I'm unsure what you're asking. Could you please include an example?

By the way, there is an `|` operator in Ruby, it's called the "bitwise or" operator; Here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-7C

Comment: You mean block variables ? Like this `(1..5).each do |x| puts  x end` or `{|x| puts x}`

Comment: Are these `| |`s preceded by `{`s or the `do` keyword?

Comment: I've voted to close the question because of it being too broad. It is at present also unclear, but if clarified I suspect the reference is to block variables, in which case explaining what blocks are is much too general a topic for an SO question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This information is surprisingly hard to find in the Ruby docs if you don't already know where to look.

Comment: @Schwern, I'm sure you're right, but it's not hard to find in any introductory book on Ruby, a better source for learning the language than exclusive reliance on Ruby docs.

Comment: @Виктор Yes, that is exactly what I'm talking about

Answer (score 6):

These are arguments to a closure, a little anonymous function.

```
my_method do |argument1, argument2|
  puts argument1, argument2
end
```

`|argument1, argument2|` says it takes two arguments. Just like if you wrote a method you'd say `def method(argument1, argument2)`. Then `my_method` can accept the closure using `&` and call it using [`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-call).

```
def my_method(&block)
  block.call(23, 42)
end
```

This is how Ruby does iterators. For example, here's how you'd implement `map`.

```
def my_map(list, &block)
  list.each do |element|
    block.call(element)
  end
end

my_map([23, 42, 99]) do |element|
  puts element
end
```

Or you can use `yield` which implicitly calls the block and it's slightly faster.

```
def my_map(list)
  list.each do |element|
    yield element
  end
end
```

A method can check if a block was passed in with [`block_given?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F). This is how, for example, [`File.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-open) can either return an open filehandle, or it can give it to a block and close it when the block is done.

```
def open(filename, mode='r')
  file = File.new(filename, mode)
  if block_given?
    yield file
    file.close
  else
    file
  end
end

# open foo.txt
puts open("foo.txt")

# open foo.txt, execute the block, and close it
open("foo.txt") do |file|
  puts file.read
end
```

This is very useful for when you need to take action, such as closing a file or shutting down a connection, once the work is done,

For more see [Block Arguments in the Ruby Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument).